# How to install node js for Hyperledger-fabric development environment?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following the hyperledger-fabric guide to create first network example, as prerequisites it asks for nodejs 8.x versions. My pc already have nodejs 11.15.0 since that version is needed for other development environment  i cannot uninstall node-11 and install nodejs 8.x version.

What are the best options to solve this problem ?
Any suggestion highly appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).Nvm helps to maintain multiple node env on a system.
use this [guide](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-nvm-node-version-manager-node-js-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) to install nvm.